# How to parameterize this paraboloid?

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure how to parameterize the following equation for a paraboloid. I'm not looking for the answer, but a guide in the right direction

$z = 4x^2 + 9y^2 - 1$

Answer (score 0):

You want a (smooth) map $\varphi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that its image is the paraboloid. In this case you can take the projection $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y)$ and see that it has a section $\varphi(x,y)=(x,y,g(x,y))$ that gives the parametrization.

Another way to arrive at such map is to use the implicit function theorem for $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(x,y,z) = 4x^2+9y^2 -1 -z
$$

Comment: When parameterizing the equation $z=x2+y2−1$ i set $x=r∗cos(teta)$ and $y=r∗sin(teta)$, but how does z become $z=r2−1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You need to obtain the same coefficient multiplying $x^2$ and $y^2$. For this, choose convenient $a$ and $b$ in $$x=ar\cos\theta, \; y=br\sin\theta.$$